# Mean shift algorithm formula

Tags: image-processing, kernel, clustering

I am watching a lecture on [mean shift clustering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8B3RZVqgOo&t=2137s). In the video, the mean shift vector is first defined and then it's relation to the gradient of a kernel density estimate is shown. The mean shift vector is defined as $$M_h(y) = [\frac{1}{n_x}\sum_{i=1}^{n_x}x_i] - y_0$$ where $n_x$ are the points around the **region of interest** and $x_i$ are the datapoints. $y_0$ is the initial estimate of the mean and $M_h(y)$ is the shift vector that moves $y_0$ in the direction of higher probability density.

The mean shift vector that is derived from taking the gradient of density estimate is $$M_h(y) = [\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_ig_i}{\sum_{i=1}^ng_i} - x]$$ where $g_i$ is the gradient of the kernel function for data point $x_i$

In this case, $n$ represents the total number of points in the data, but $n_x$ represents the number of points in the region of interest. How do we reconcile this difference ?